# Отнять от даты 1 день

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть дата 2018-11-12 как от нее отнять 1 день в js?
`urrDate.setDate(CurrDate.getDate() - 1);` так не работает, пишет:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sdate.getDate is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего с помощью библиотеки [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

А если без библиотеки, то получи вначале метку времени и вычти из неё день в миллисекундах:

```
const dayMilliseconds = 24*60*60*1000;

var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() - dayMilliseconds);
```

Comment: const dayMilliseconds = 24*60*60*1000;
alert(sdate.setTime(sdate.getTime() - dayMilliseconds));
Uncaught TypeError: sdate.getTime is not a function

Comment: покажите весь код

Comment: Потому что Ваша `sdate` - строка, а не дата.

Comment: ага, работает, только выводит формата 1540000000 а как преобразовать к виду 2018-11-11?

Comment: методами getDate, getMonth, getFullYear